# How to reach _id of document when it's in the parent data context?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This seems like an open-and-shut case for `Template.parentData()`, but to this day I've never once managed to get that bad boy working properly.

**What I want is an event that updates a document depending on which button was clicked, but the buttons are themselves dependent on an array buried deeper in the document, where the `_id` doesn't exist.**

Here's what I have:

First, a helper that sets the context `peopleList`:

```
Template.people.helpers({
  peopleList: function() {
    return People.find()
  }
```

Which I use to iterate through in the HTML, printing out the first and last name of each person stored in the database, as well as their favorite colors (extraneous markup removed):

```
{{#each peopleList}}
  <li>
    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    {{#each favoriteColors}} <button>{{this}}</button> {{/each}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

It should be noted at this point that `favoriteColors` is a key inside the document which holds an array. So the whole thing looks something like this:

```
{
  firstName: "Johnny",
  lastName: "Boy",
  favoriteColors: ["red", "blue", "blanchedAlmond"]
}
```

Imagine now that I want to be able to press any of these buttons, which hold the favorite colors, to set the, uh, super-duper favorite color or something. So a button click on **blanchedAlmond** should update the document, adding the key `masterColor` with the value `blanchedAlmond`.

The event:

```
'click button': function() {
    var masterColor = ????
    var docId = ????
    Meteor.call('setMasterColor', masterColor, docId)
  }
```

I could provide HTML `data`-tags that hold the color value (because `this` inside the event spits out some weird array with each letter separated for some reason) and even the `_id` with `{{../_id}}`, but that feels like cheating, and I really want to learn how to do the same thing inside a helper or an event.

I strongly feel like this would be a case for `Template.parentData()` but it returns nothing at all when I `console.dir` it. What should I do?

Comment: Could we see the `setMasterColor` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion around `parentData` has to do with the event context. The event is attached to the template whose context is something that isn't a person or a color. Whenever you get the feeling that you need to start littering your code with `data-` attributes, the answer is nearly always to add more templates. For example:

**html**

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul>
    {{#each peopleList}}
      {{> person}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="person">
  <li>
    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    {{#each favoriteColors}}
      {{> color}}
    {{/each}}
  </li>
</template>

<template name="color">
  <button>{{this}}</button>
</template>
```

**js**

```js
Template.color.events({
  'click button': function() {
    // this context is a color - remember to convert it to a string
    var masterColor = String(this);

    // the parent context is a person
    var docId = Template.parentData(1)._id;

    return Meteor.call('setMasterColor', masterColor, docId);
  }
});
```